# Count in Joins in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two tables (post.id is primary key which become seconday key in like.post_id )

table "post"

```
id      user_id     image
1       10          abc.jpg
2       20          xyz.jpg
3       10          ajb.jpg
```

Table "Like"

```
id      user_id     post_id         likes
1       10          1               1
2       20          2               1
3       10          1               1
4       10          1               1
3       10          3               1
```

now i want whenever i pass user_id then i wan to get all post of users with number of likes of posts

i tried with following code but not worked,

```
SELECT selfie_info.id,selfie_info.user_id,selfie_info.image, (SELECT COUNT(m.likes)FROM post_likes m WHERE m.user_id='10') as total_likes FROM selfie_info where user_id='10'
```

how can i do this ? i want result like following (if i pass user_id=10 )

```
user_id     post_id     likes
10          1           3
10          3           1
```

Comment: Is ` likes` in Table "Like" always 1 ?

Comment: @splash58 : Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.user_id, p.id AS post_id, COUNT(l.id) AS total_likes
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.post_id =p.id
WHERE p.user_id=10 GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: If there's possiblity to have values in `likes` column in table `like` higher than 1, you should use SUM(l.likes) insted of COUNT(l.id)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select pl.post_id, count(*) as numlikes,
       si.*
from selfie_info si join
     post_likes pl
     on si.user_id = pl.user_id
where si.user_id = 10
group by si.user_id, si.post_id
```

You can use `si.*` in the `select`, even though this is a `group by` query because you are aggregating by the primary key/unique id in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You have all necessary data in table "like"
You can use one select from "like" table.

```
select user_id, post_id, sum(likes) as likes from like where user_id = 10;
```

You need to count or sum likes? 
Depends on you needs You can sum(likes) or count(*) likes